# Update column in SQL with phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin

I have a table in the phpMyAdmin database

> [image]

How to import data from Excel, only for the ACCOUNT column and starting from row 1?

I have tried importing and setting column names "ACCOUNT", but the import results start from the last row of previous data and do not start from row 1

> [image]

Thanks you so much for helping me, sorry for bad english

Comment: Truncate table before import?

Comment: truncate for delete all the contents? i need to keep the existed field and add to account column only.

Comment: You can't import directly to a column in an existing table, perhaps import to a staging table including some identifier you can than use to update original table. Please add table definition, sample data and desired outcome as text.